# Как спроектировать и построить свой движок для сайта(CMS)

Tags: php, cms, mysql

Пишу специально для своего сайта но универсальный.
Так что хочу узнать теоретические вопросы построения движка.
**Вопросы:**

1. Как спроектировать архетектуру?
2. Как написать модульную расширяемую cms?
3. Стоит ли писать для него фреймворк?
4. Как должна выглядеть БД

Comment: А что значит "универсальный"? Это будет движок, на который можно и сайт-визитку повесить, и интернет магазин, и социальную сеть etc.?

P.S. Моё личное мнение - это бесмысленно тратить время на "миксеры". WordPress, например, тем и хорош, что заточен под определенное направление - блог. Именно поэтому для блога в подавляющем большинстве используют именно эту CMS, а не Joomla, к примеру.

Comment: Писать то пишите, но в итоге выйдет тот же самый фреймворк коих кучи, только без документации, компьюнити и обновлений от профессиональных и не очень программистов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Используйте паттерны проектирования, для сайтов хорошо подходит [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#MVC). Используйте готовый http-сервер, наиболее простой и производительный вариант связи с сервером - fastcgi. Хороший http-сервер должен уметь обрабатывать запросы параллельно.
2. Реализуйте шаблоны страниц и возможность подключать внешние библиотеки, скрипты и программы. Задокументируйте API для всего этого.
3. Можете взять готовый, если нет подходящего - пишите свой.
4. БД зависит от цели сайта, но может содержать и предопределённую часть структуры, обычно это список пользователей и прав. СУБД должна обеспечить параллельность запросов.

Answer (score -2):

Всё зависит от Вас:

> 1. Как Вам удобнее.
> 2. Какие Вы имеете знания.
> 3. Для чего Вам нужен этот сайт.
> 4. Какие технические решения Вы будете использовать.

---

Список можно продолжать до бесконечности; но если Вы думаете что Вам сейчас напишут план разработки CMS, то Вы ошибаетесь.

---

> *Главное **`ИМХО`** - знание **`ООП`**, **`HTML`**, **`XML`**, а подробнее можно узнать, ковыряя уже кем-то написанные **`CMS`***

Comment: > ковыряя а подробнее можно узнать, ковыряя Wordpress

За весь свой опыт с этой типа "CMS" не взял ничего что мне моггло бы пригодится в создании собственных!

Comment: @Palmervan, ок, тогда так XD

Comment: @niki-timofe ковыряя уже кем-то написанную CMS можно ещё узнать много новых выражений и пожеланий.

Comment: @Palmervan, абсолютно согласен! А зачастую CMS так криво лепят так называемые "разработчики", что в последствии произвести атаку на сервис, "стоящий" на одной из таких CMS, может человек, обладающий базовыми знаниями Js и HTML! Даже, если рассмотреть всю ту же WordPress: каждый месяц в сети публикуют "букет", так называемую порцию новых багов и недочетов, найденных там. Более 90% из них представляют из себя потенциальную уязвимость( активная XSS, например! ). Так, что, @niki-timofe, не стоит "учиться" на чужих CMS - себе во вред же!

Comment: Стоит попробовать штук 7 больших CMS, чтобы понять, что в них не хватает и не повторять их стратегические ошибки